# Django not filtering by date

Tags: python, django

I have an Appointment model as follows:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I have 3 entries for testing purposes:

```
Appointment.objects.all()
```

returns

```
<QuerySet [<Appointment: 2018-06-13 14:00:00-04:00>, <Appointment: 2018-06-13 12:00:00-04:00>, <Appointment: 2018-06-14 14:30:00-04:00>]>
```

today is:

```
today = timezone.now()
2018-06-13 18:59:09.884977+00:00
```

I want to get tomorrow appointments, so I do:

```
tomorrow = today.date()+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(start_date__date=tomorrow)
```

or

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(start_date__date=datetime.date(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day))
```

or

```
appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(start_date__year=tomorrow.year, start_date__month=tomorrow.month, start_date__day=tomorrow.day)
```

In any case it should return a Queryset with one entry, but returns an empty one.

Anyone?

Comment: i try you case in the my local app and all works fine.

Comment: Same, it's working in my local app too.

Comment: That's weird.. Maybe it has something to do with my work environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try use only `appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(start_date__day=tomorrow.day)`

If that does not work, perhaps you problem in different time zone: tomorrow val **+00:00** and in model **-04:00**.

Answer (score 0):

```
tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
Mymodel.objects.filter(date_time_field__contains=tomorrow)
```

This did the trick for me. I don't find it the most elegant way but, hey, it works